# Getting connection reset by peer in Dropwizard Application for HealthCheck

Tags: jetty, dropwizard, health-check

We are running a drop wizard application and we are getting error `Connection reset by peer` when doing health check from Prometheus. Also after we receive this error the server stops responding until we restart the server. Below is the health check code.

```
Response response = null;
        try {
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/test");
            Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            response = invocationBuilder.get();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(null != response && response.getStatus() == 302) {
            return Result.healthy();
        }
        return Result.unhealthy("Fail...");
```

While executing the line return Result.healthy(); we are getting below error intermittently in production environment.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - write exception
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192) ~[jetty-io-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:408) ~[jetty-io-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:302) ~[jetty-io-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:129) [jetty-io-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:676) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:246) [jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:208) [jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:471) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:763) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:801) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:142) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:135) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.close(HttpOutput.java:166) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.close(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1080) [jackson-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:1055) [jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:889) [jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlets.HealthCheckServlet.doGet(HealthCheckServlet.java:104) [metrics-servlets-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlets.AdminServlet.service(AdminServlet.java:101) [metrics-servlets-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49) [dropwizard-jetty-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:44) [dropwizard-jersey-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39) [dropwizard-jersey-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51) [dropwizard-jetty-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_302]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:172) ~[jetty-io-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Can someone suggest is there a way can reproduce this locally? Also can we fix or have workaround to avoid this. Kindly let me know if I need to provide more information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that the client disconnected and didn't finish reading the response.

The issue is entirely on the client side.

Any periodic HTTP request (eg: health check) should use proper HTTP mechanisms.

- Use HTTP/1.1 (easiest)
- Client sends `Connection: close` request header indicating that it will disconnect at the end of the exchange.
- Client reads the entire response, including response body before disconnecting.

Your code snippet is not reading the response body, do that first.

Then, if the problem still persists after that, look into setting the `Connection: close` header on the request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will check that.